# how to change a file in web-inf/classes directory in war without unpacking?

Tags: java, tomcat, war, web-inf

here is the structure of my war file.

```
MyApp.war
      WEB-INF
          classes/com/info/App.java
          classes/application.properties
          lib/
      META-INF
      test
```

just before deployment of this war to tomcat, Ops team will need to update the application.properties file.

I prefer not to explode. but just to update the war and leave for tomcat to explode during start up

I tried this

```
jar uvf MyApp.war /var/data/prod/application.properties
```

After I executed this command, I see a new file being added at root level of MyApp.war. but I want `WEB-INF/classes/application.properties` to be replaced this one. How can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it is the good approach anyway, you should **externalize** your configuration file as **it will change from one env to another**, so it should not be part of your archive. You should adapt your code to be able to read the configuration of your application from an external folder. Your Ops team will then have the same `war` to deploy on all env instead of one per env, which is much less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

How about this....

```
mkdir -p /tmp/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/classes
cp  /var/data/prod/application.properties /tmp/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/classes
jar -uvf MyApp.war -C /tmp/MyApp.war WEB-INF
rm -rf /tmp/MyApp.war
```